# Size of label changes after being set, depending on string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

I am facing an issue in getting the correct frame for two different strings. I am running two strings through the below code:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
myLabel.text = @"About Stores"
myLabel.text = @"About Rivers"

CGSize myLabelSize = CGSizeMake(70,28);
[myLabel sizeWithFont:myString.font     // <-- One of two strings
    constrainedToSize:aLabelSize 
        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Result for `myString1` => Width: 70, Height: 28
Result for `myString2` => Width: 70, Height: 14

Why there is a difference here?

Comment: What is myString.font?  What is aLabelSize?  You are missing a semicolon on the second line.

Comment: @Jason: Updated my question. Its a UILabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues I see:

## 1

NSString has no font property. You might want to replace "myString.font" with UILabel.font where the UILabel is to be replaced by the instance of UILabel you plan to use to display the string.

## 2

sizeWithFont is supposed to return a CGSize that you store in an instance of CGSize.

Seems like you're not very clear on using this. I've posted an answer on how to correctly use sizeWithFont. You should check that out here : [Place two UILabels side by side left and right without knowing string length of text in left label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891384/place-two-uilabels-side-by-side-left-and-right-without-knowing-string-length-of-t/5891439#5891439)

By the way, that's why you see a difference in the heights... I think a garbage value is being passed in as the font size argument. If you hardcode the font size argument, you'll see consistent results.

Comment: @Siddharth: I updated my question. Its not a NSString, rather a UILabel.

Comment: @Abhinav: Did you take a look at the link? Did that answer help? Are you also passing myLabel.font as the font argument in the "sizeWithFont" method?

Comment: @Siddharth: Yes, I am passing correct values to sizeWithFont and checked it with breakpoints also. For both of my texts font and constrained size are same but it is returning different results. For one text it wraps it to two line and for other keeps it in one line.

Comment: @Abhinav: Could you paste the size contraints you're passing in?

Comment: Size constraint = (70, 28). Here for one string, width comes out to be 69 and hence it is keeping that string in one line while for other it crosses 70. I am surprised because of the strings have same number of characters in it.

Comment: Well even if it's the same number of characters that does not necessarily mean that the width would be the same. Maybe that's what's happening. For example, the "w" character is definitely wider than the "l" character. This is probably what's happening here :)

Comment: Yes you are right. So, is there any work around for this here? If I try to reduce the constrained size, it mess up other labels :-(!

Comment: Well the workaround would depend on what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to achieve the same width/height for both labels? What I do while working with labels is set number of lines to 0. That way the number of lines can be as big as possible. Then when using sizeWithFont I set the width constraint to be the label width and the height to be something big like 2000 . This allows the labels to be as tall as possible, constrained to the width of the label. What I then do is use the size.height from the CGSize returned by sizeWithFont and set the label's height to that.

Comment: Which basically means I have UILabels which have a fixed width but dynamic height depending on the text they display.

Answer (score 0):

just replace the code n give a try.....i don kno if it works jus check :)

```
[myLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:11]     
constrainedToSize:myLabelSize  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

and also ";" is missing in label`

myLabel.text = @"About Stores";
myLabel.text = @"About Rivers";`

regards..

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference because the system font is Helvetica, which is a variable-sized font. The text in myString1 is maginally wider than the text in myString2, so the string needs to wrap to a second line in order to fit. Since you specified 2 lines max and UILineBreakModeWordWrap, that's what you get. If you want it to fit in one line, make myLabelSize a little wider or else use a smaller font size.